# Unable to capture steady RTSP video using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video, rtsp

I'm trying to capture a RTSP video from an IP camera using OpenCV with the following snippet

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(RTSP_URL)
while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if not ret:
        cam = cv2.VideoCapture(RTSP_URL)
```

This works, but after some time frames are lost for unknown reasons and it seems unable to reconnect to RTSP stream, despite the last line. Using VLC the RTSP stream is played steadily.
Is there a more robust way to capture a RTSP stream?

Comment: why do you always re-start videocapture ? `cam = cv2.VideoCapture(RTSP_URL)` seems problematic to use in a while loop

Comment: looks like "error handling" in case the capture failed. does not happen as long as frames are returned

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I agree, but I couldn't find better ways to "reconnect" to the video in case the capture fails

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I thought so. Is it better to `cam.release()` before the last line?

Comment: it's a good idea because at the time the old VideoCap will probably still hold the device

Answer (score 0):

I would recomment to use pyav instead, because error handling is better and you have better control of it. (https://pyav.org/docs/develop/api/error.html)

this is an untested example but should give you a way to go.

```py
import av
import time
import threading

class RTSPStream:
    def __init__(self, rtsp_url, reconnect_interval=10):
        self.rtsp_url = rtsp_url
        self.reconnect_interval = reconnect_interval
        self.container = None
        self.should_stop = threading.Event()

    def open_stream(self):
        try:
            self.container = av.open(self.rtsp_url)
        except av.AVError as e:
            print("Error opening RTSP stream:", e)

    def process_frames(self):
        while not self.should_stop.is_set():
            try:
                for frame in self.container.decode(video=0):
                    print("Frame timestamp:", frame.time)
            except av.AVError as e:
                print("AVError:", e)
                if e.errno in (av.AVERROR_EXIT, av.AVERROR_EOF):
                    print("Stream ended.")
                    break
                elif e.errno == av.AVERROR_TIMEOUT:
                    print("Read timeout. Reconnecting in", self.reconnect_interval, "seconds.")
                elif e.errno == av.AVERROR_INVALIDDATA:
                    print("Invalid data received. Skipping frame.")
                elif e.errno == 401:
                    print("Unauthorized: Check your RTSP credentials.")
                    break
                elif e.errno == 404:
                    print("RTSP stream not found (404).")
                    break
                else:
                    print("Unknown AVError:", e)
                    break
                
                // TODO: call this not an all errors 
                time.sleep(self.reconnect_interval)
                self.open_stream()

    def start(self):
        while not self.should_stop.is_set():
            if self.container is None:
                self.open_stream()
            if self.container is not None:
                self.process_frames()

    def stop(self):
        self.should_stop.set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rtsp_url = "rtsp://your_rtsp_stream_url"
    stream = RTSPStream(rtsp_url)
    streaming_thread = threading.Thread(target=stream.start)
    streaming_thread.start()
    time.sleep(60)
    stream.stop()
    streaming_thread.join()
```